# Python docs: confusing terminology of modules and submodules

Tags: python, python-module

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) say: `Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a submodule named B in a package named A.`

A package is defined in the docs a dir with some either subdirs or files. Those subdirs would be subpackages, following this convention. A submodule then would be a module in the subdir, or the subpackage?

Would it be more clear to say module name A.B designates a **module** named B in a package named A?

And suppose dir A has a subdir C which contains file D, then one would say D, fully A.C.D, is a **submodue** of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the glossary on the term [module](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module):

> An object that serves as an organizational unit of Python code. Modules have a namespace containing arbitrary Python objects. Modules are loaded into Python by the process of importing.

... and on the term [package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package):

> A Python module which can contain submodules or recursively, subpackages. Technically, a package is a Python module with an `__path__` attribute.

So every (sub-)package is also a module, but the opposite is not true.

Considering the package layout you gave as an example:

```
A
├── B.py
├── C
│   ├── D.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

Here, `A, B, C, D` are all modules (you can import them via their name: `import A` or `import A.B` or `import A.C` or `import A.C.D`). However only `A, C` are considered packages.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `So every (sub-)package is also a (sub-)module, but the opposite is not true.` Since it looks like a top level dir can be called both package and module?

Comment: The prefix "sub-" only indicates some hierarchy, but it doesn't change what it is, a package or a module. And packages are also modules, no matter where in the hierarchy.

Comment: For further clarity, I would add to the answer that a dir (package) can exisit without any files or sibdirs and still have names (symbols) defined in its \__init\__.py.

Comment: Well, `__init__.py` *is* a file. If it doesn't contain any files then it's a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).